# Design pattern for consuming REST services with Java Webclient

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, rest, design-patterns

I need to consume few REST services in sequential order and parse them into Java Objects and persist those Java Objects in DB.

I have written a web client which sent the request, parse the response and return the response in RootNodeObject.

```
public clas RootNodeObject {

private Auth;

private DeviceDetails;

private HostDetails;

}
```

When I sent webclient.get("/Auth") it returns  RootNodeObject which contains Auth object populated in it.
When I sent webclient.get("/deviceDetails") it returns  RootNodeObject which contains DeviceDetails object populated in it.

In a similar way, I have to sent 8-10 request to get all required data.

After that, I have written a mapper class which will convert  Auth and DeviceDetails object into Hibernate Entity classes and persist it in DB.

This looks very rigid design.Any design pattern for the above code or any better design that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

[ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/intro.html) is exactly what you need. Below is the text from their site. They also have implementations in various [programming languages](http://reactivex.io/languages.html)

You can ues the [merge operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) to combine results of various observables into a single one. You can find one example [here](https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/combining/ObservableMerge.java)

> ReactiveX is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by >using observable sequences.
>
> It extends the observer pattern to support sequences of data and/or events and adds operators that allow you to compose sequences together declaratively while abstracting away concerns about things like low-level threading, synchronization, thread-safety, concurrent data structures, and non-blocking I/O.
>
> **Why Use Observables?**
>
> The ReactiveX Observable model allows you to treat streams of asynchronous events with the same sort of simple, composable operations that you use for collections of data items like arrays. It frees you from tangled webs of callbacks, and thereby makes your code more readable and less prone to bugs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I can use it in my case?

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: You can find many rxjava tutorials online for eg., http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html.

Comment: Any other solution/design apart from using ReactiveX since I am not using Java 1.8?